# MySQL in CentOS can't start service

Tags: mysql

after I reboot my server, I can't start mysql:

`$ sudo service mysql start`

`$ Starting MySQL. ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.`

"/var/log/mysqld.log" shows:

`150225 21:39:49 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150225 21:39:49 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
150225 21:39:49 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
150225 21:39:49  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
150225 21:39:49  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 0 37356
150225 21:39:49  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 0 44233
150225 21:39:49  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
150225 21:39:49  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
150225 21:39:49 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
150225 21:39:49 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/iZ23aa67ovhZ.pid ended`

and my hard dirve isn't full.

here is the status of /var/lib/mysql:

`drwxrwxrwx   2 mysql root      4096 Feb 26 16:43 .
drwxr-xr-x. 21 root  root      4096 Feb 25 19:38 ..
-rw-rw----   1 mysql mysql 10485760 Feb 25 19:38 ibdata1
-rw-rw----   1 mysql mysql  5242880 Feb 26 16:43 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----   1 mysql mysql  5242880 Feb 25 19:38 ib_logfile1`

and here is /etc/my.cnf:

`[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

and there is no mysql_install_db on the server:
`bash: mysql_install_db: command not found`
and when I run mysql_safe, it shows:

`150226 16:58:50 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
150226 16:58:50 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150226 16:58:50 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended`

thanks a lot!

Comment: That's look strange. Did you change anything in the my.cnf configuration file? Some tables may be corrupt... check your datadir. Check also the rights on this directory. If you had moved it, try to restart with disabling selinux.

Comment: @JérémyMunoz I didn't change anything in my.cnf

Comment: rpm -ql mysql-server | grep mysql_install_db

Answer (score 1):

> 150225 21:39:49 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege
>   tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist

To fix this issue you simply just have to tell mysql where to look not that the default installation is moved. You can do that with:

```
mysql_install_db –user=mysql –ldata=/newlocation
```

once you do that you can restart mysql

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

If it wouldn't help:

1. Uninstalled mysql using `yum remove mysql*`
2. Recursively deleted `/usr/bin/mysql` and `/var/lib/mysql`
3. Also deleted the file `/etc/my.cnf.rmp`
4. Used `ps -e` to check the processes to make sure mysql wasn't still running.
5. Rebooted server with `reboot`
6. Ran `yum install mysql-server`.  This also seems to install the mysql client as a dependency.
7. gave mysql ownership and group priveleges with `chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql` and `chgrp -R mysql /var/lib/mysql`
8. Used `service mysqld start` to start MySQL Daemon.

> 150225 21:39:49  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally! InnoDB:
>   Starting crash recovery. InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from
>   the .ibd files... InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
>   from the doublewrite InnoDB: buffer...

This is normal output after a crash. InnoDB is designed to recover automatically in these cases, but it may take some time. Usually minutes, but possibly hours if the crash occurred when you had thousands of pages of modified data in memory, and your disks are slow.

InnoDB can recover by itself in most cases, with no data loss.

To start the recovery, first, you have to make use of the ‘innodb_force_recovery’ directive within the /etc/my.cnf. If you are not familiar with this, please read the following documentation, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html. If you are familiar, please proceed.

Sometimes, InnoDB will be only moderately damaged and can repair itself. Add “innodb_force_recovery = #” to a new line under the [mysqld] section of the /etc/my.cnf. Ensure to replace the # with the magnitude of recovery in which you are requiring. **If you attempt to use anything beyond a magnitude of 4, you run an extreme risk of further corruption, meaning that your time and effort would be for nothing.** In this instance, as we are attempting self-repair, only use 1 or 2. Once you have added the new line, restart the MySQL server and check the logs (/var/lib/mysql/server.hostname.com.err) to check if the instance successfully repaired itself.

Comment: what do you mean by "beyond a magnitude of 4" & I've updated the question with more information

Comment: I don't want to lost my data in mysql, how can I backup my database and reload it into mysql after reinstall mysql?

Comment: you can find all your databases. Stop mysqld if run. copy them. And try to restore.